# Making IDEA diff viewer show inline diff of selected line

Tags: intellij-idea, diff

Does anyone know how to activate the old behaviour in Intellij's diff viewer to show the currently selected lines from the left and right panes as an inline diff at the bottom of the screen?

Intellij's diff can compare two files in either side-by-side or inline mode. I find side-by-side mode easier to quickly identify structure of changes, but one disadvantage is it's harder to see what's changed on long lines (because often only the first half of the line is visible in the split windows unless you have a biiig monitor).
I vaguely recall, long long ago, intellij's diff viewer would put an inline diff of the 'current' lines in the left and right half, at the bottom of the screen. This showed the line from the left half all the way across the window, followed by the line from the right half, so you didn't have to keep scrolling either pane horizontally to see differences at the ends of lines.

Alternatively a direct link to the developers whom I could encourage to bring that back would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks for enlightenment.

A quick hunt in SO and over at Jetbrains didn't reveal any sign that this was even ever possible, so I'm somewhat questioning my memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it was only possible to select the panes position - either Left| Right or Top | Bottom, and it worked in the commit dialog only. When Unified view appeared that option was removed.

And AFAIR, there was no additional pane showing Unified diff of a selected chunk ever. Here is the request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-36387, but there are no plans to implement it at the moment.

BTW, all Diff windows have a Unified view for the entire file now, and switching between modes keeps caret position. So as a workaround, if lines are too long in a chunk, it is possible to switch to Unified view to see the entire line, and then get back.

Comment: Pls could you clarify _only possible to select the panes position_ ? (PS Useful tip about caret preservation on switching between unified/side-side views, and also issue link **thanks**.)

Comment: In the old versions, it was possible to select how Diff panes are positioned in the Commit dialog. Possible options were Horizontally (old version on the left, current version on the right, like it is now), or Vertically (old version on top, current version on bottom).